# @Html.ValidationMessageFor is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

```
//Index Page (view) /Employee/Index
@model DataAnotaionExample.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form action="./Add">
Enter Name=@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>Model.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

//Employee Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DataAnotaionExample.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }enter code here
    }
}
```

Model Class Employee.cs

```
namespace DataAnotaionExample.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my code, If I keep the Name field blank then it will not throw the error like the field is required.

This Code Created in Asp.Net MVC5 Framework

Comment: I see you're not included `jQuery.validate` (and `jQuery.validate.unobtrusive`) library inside script tag(s), hence `ValidationMessageFor` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have added

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script
```

at the end of your layout page:

Answer (score 0):

First you have add razor like this

```
@model DataAnotaionExample.Models.Employee
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

<form action="./Add">   
       //this one 
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


Enter Name=@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>Model.Name)
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you should  like validation script like this in your "_Layout.cshtml" page

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Or you can use this script in your App_Start->BundleConfig

```
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
       "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
       "~Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
```

));

I hope this code is useful for you.